# ActionBarActivity with TabHost

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabhost, android-tabs, android-support-library

I am developing an app, with minimum sdk level 7 and that's why I use support library and ActionBarActivity to have a proper ActionBar, but also the layout of my page contains four tabs on the bottom of the activity, and as i already extend ActionBarActivity, I cannot extend TabActivity.
The problem is when I write

```
public class HomePageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private TabHost mTabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_homepage);

    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = mTabHost.newTabSpec("TAB1");
    tab1.setIndicator("TAB 1");

    Intent popularContentIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, GuideActivity.class);
    tab1.setContent(popularContentIntent);
    mTabHost.addTab(tab1);
```

I get the error "Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)?'" at the line when I trying to add tab to the tabhost.
If I try to set the id of the view in the tab.setContent(..) like tab.setContent(R.id.tab1) and have a view in the xml with the id tab1, I get the error that the view with such a number cannot be found.

My layout:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        </Button>
    </TabWidget>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is it possible somehow to have layout with tabs and actionbar at the same time? What I do wrong? What could be other alternatives?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You must call `mTabHost.setup()` before making any calls to `addTab(...)`.

Comment: @Squonk - that is what i do: 
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

Comment: Sorry, I skim-read your post and went straight to the error that is being reported.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in logcat other than the one you mention in the question?

Comment: @Squonk no, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1):

`TabActivity` was deprecated in API level 13. The updated [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) recommends using `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost` instead.

An even better method would be to use the `ViewPager` sample provided [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

Comment: The OP isn't using `TabActivity` - they're using `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: I need four fixed tabs in the bottom of the page, ViewPager does not allow me to have such a layout.

Comment: Like I said, use `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost`. `ViewPager` was simply another alternative.

Comment: I just pointed out `TabActivity` since the documentation suggests alternatives to using that with the ActionBar and fragments.